# How to get the row hover to show an appropriate cursor

Tags: jquery, datatables

Since my jQuery DataTable rows are sortable via drag and drop, how do I get the script to show the appropriate cursor when hovering?  It is not obvious that you can drag the rows.  If you click and drag, the cursor turns to a move cursor, but during hover you get the I bar or a standard arrow cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use the cursor:move rule in your row's css.

```
tr:hover {
    cursor:move;
}
```

Adjust the css accordingly with any classes you would like to attach this css too (for example .my-draggable-table tr:hover {...})

Comment: Looks like best place:  table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover

Answer (score 0):

This is done in CSS:

```
.foo {
  cursor: move;
}
```

Or:

```
.bar {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```